# Выборка уникальных значений за определенное время SQL

Tags: mysql

Коллеги, привет!
Нужно написать SQL запрос для решения следующей задачи:
Есть таблица1, содержащая 2 столбца «код» и «дата».
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Например, сегодня (04.09.2020) я добавил новые значения, из них мне нужно вывести список уникальны значений, которые не использовались последние 2 дня.
Должно получиться:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT DISTINCT t1.*
FROM source t1
LEFT JOIN source t2 ON t1.code = t2.code
                   AND t1.date <= t2.date + INTERVAL 2 DAY
WHERE t1.date = CURRENT_DATE
  AND t2.code IS NULL
```

> Можно этот запрос адаптировать для access ?

```
SELECT DISTINCT t1.*
FROM source t1
LEFT JOIN source t2 ON t1.code = t2.code
                   AND t1.[date] <= DateAdd("d", 2, t2.[date])
WHERE t1.[date] = Date()
  AND t2.code IS NULL
```

Comment: Спасибо, огромное! Можно этот запрос адаптировать для access ?

Comment: @Mr.V А какие сложности-то? в режиме SQL запросто вводится... только не открывай в режиме конструктора - вдруг Access поломает? он этим славится...

Comment: я пробовал, выдает ошибку. Можно как-то с вами связаться, чтобы вы помогли решить несколько схожих задач на возмездной основе ?

Comment: добавил, напишите, плз.

Comment: @Mr.V Принято, убирайте.